# iOS - MPMoviePlayerViewController not playing streaming URL

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm having a streaming URL which is something like "http://myserver.com/master.m3u8". (this is dummy URL)
This URL is playing fine in the safari browser on iPhone.
But when playing the same within the app using following code, i'm facing some issues:

```
NSURL* theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/master.m3u8"];

MPMoviePlayerViewController* moviePlayerViewController  = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;        
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
```

The problem when playing within the app is that, after sometime the screen turns to black color. But i'm still able to hear the audio.
How can I debug where is the issue.

Can some one help me who faced similar issue please?

Comment: I am having the same issue, the screen doesn't turns black but it shows the Quicktime logo with audio images. I noticed that sometimes the streaming recovers itself from this, but it takes some time. The issue is not a coding issue, because if I place the app using 3G against another using WIFI, both live videos stop at the same time, however WI-FI recovers faster. Did you manage to workaround it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a standard m3u8 file the lowest version of the video will include an audio only version of the stream. So if the bandwidth is to low the player may switch to this stream and play audio only.

I haven't found a solution yet to do something meaningful in the app when this happens(for example pause the video and wait until the bandwidth is sufficient to play the next higher version of the stream which has video again) but if you can tweak the m3u8 or the encoding process you could just remove the audio only version from your m3u8. Then the player would switch to the lowest video stream and pause if the bandwidth isn't enough to show it.

Please keep in mind that you have to provide this to the App Review team when submitting the app to the store. This is mentioned in this Technical QA from Apple: [Resolving App Store Approval Issues for HTTP Live Streaming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1767/_index.html)

> Note: As the baseline 64 kbps maximum audio-only HTTP Live stream requirement is specifically for streaming over a cellular network, if your application is self-restricting to Wi-Fi only HTTP Live Streaming and you choose to not supply a baseline 64 kbps audio-only stream, you must provide this information to the App Review team. Developers can include this information in the Review Notes field for your application.